# Subroutine not fully executing when called indirectly

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet, with the following two subroutines in it (there's a lot more to them, but I've stripped out all the code not directly relevant to the question):

```
Sub HF_Reset()
    Feats_Reset
End Sub

Sub Feats_Reset()
    Range("TblAllFeatsSelected").Value = CVErr(xlErrNA)
    Range("Test").Value = "Success"
    Range("Test2").Value = 1
End Sub
```

`Test` is a single cell, `Test2` is a two-cell range, `TblAllFeatsSelected` is a large range.

If I call Feats_Reset, it executes absolutely fine, does what it's intended to do. If I call HF_Reset, then `Test`gets "Success" put into it, and `Test2` is filled with 1s, but `TblAllFeatsSelected` doesn't change. I have absolutely no clue what's going on - any ideas?

For debugging purposes, I've also tried setting `Range("TblAllFeatsSelected").Value = 1` and `Range("TblAllFeatsSelected").Value = 0`, and again it works fine when calling `Feats_Reset` but not when calling `HF_Reset`.

EDIT: I've played some more, and traced the problem to another subroutine called in Feats_Reset. I suspect I'm not going to be able to provide enough information here to get a useful answer - it's a complicated sheet, and there's a lot of interactions that could be the problem. Bother.

EDIT2: Found the problem. The subroutine was setting `TblAllFeatsSelected` to the value of another range, which when calling from HF_Reset needed to have an `Application.Calculate` or it would justset it back to what it used to be.

Is there any way I can delete this question as not useful? It's such a specific thing, I doubt it could help anyone else.

Comment: So if you run *exactly that posted code* (and not any code you haven't shown) it doesn't work properly if you call `HF_reset`?

Comment: Where have you declared your variable xlErrNA? You might also benefit from referencing the relevant sheets when referencing the Ranges (eg Sheet1.Range("RangeName"))

Answer (score 0):

Problem Exists Between Keyboard and Chair. I was missing an `Application.Calculate` in a completely different part of the code.